# Matlab onCleanup function not executed

Tags: matlab

I ran into the following issue in MATLAB R2013a, which for some reason I do not understand does not call the onCleanup function when in a function a timer (including a TimerFcn) is defined.

I add two minimal examples showing the problem:

first the working version where the cleanup routine is called as expected:

```
function mytest(time)
  t = timer();
  myclean = onCleanup(@() disp('function ended'));
  pause(time);
end
```

and now the buggy version in which the cleanup is not called (neither when the function ends normally or when ctrl+c is pressed)

```
function mytest2(time)
  t = timer();
  t.TimerFcn = @(o,s)disp(' ... waiting for some time'); 
  myclean = onCleanup(@() disp('function ends'));
  pause(time);
end
```

I could not find any hints in documentation why the timer or more specific the definition of the TimerFcn would change the execution of the cleanup code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ouch - this is nasty. It's **not** a bug, but it's certainly not what you'd expect from the documentation, and it's not what you'd want. Fortunately it's pretty easy to work around.

Firstly, what's happening?

Well, `onCleanup` returns you an onCleanup object. This is an object whose sole purpose is to have a destructor method that is set to your `@() disp('function ends')`. When the object goes out of scope (which you would expect to be at the end of the function `mytest2`), it gets deleted, its destructor method executes, and your message gets displayed. That's what you expect, I think.

But when you create the anonymous function `@(o,s)disp(' ... waiting for some time')`, and assign it to the `TimerFcn` of your timer, it takes a copy of the entire current workspace of the function `mytest2`, including the `onCleanup` object. The timer is created in the base workspace (not the function workspace), and remains in existence even at the end of the function, along with the `onCleanup` object, which then never goes out of scope, never gets deleted, its destructor function never runs, and you don't get your message.

Note that:

1. If you run `a = timerfindall; delete(a);` in the base workspace, you will get your message, as you've explicitly deleted the timer along with the `onCleanup` object.
2. This behaviour about anonymous functions taking a copy of their entire workspace is fully documented, although you may not be aware of it, and although you clearly don't want it to work like that here. It's nasty.

Fortunately, it's easy to work around:

```
function mytest3(time)
  t = timer();
  setTimerFcn(t)
  myclean = onCleanup(@() disp('function ends'));
  pause(time);
end

function setTimerFcn(t)
  t.TimerFcn = @(o,s)disp(' ... waiting for some time'); 
end
```

Now, when the anonymous function is created it only takes a copy of its *local* workspace (i.e. from the subfunction `setTimerFcn`), which does not include the `onCleanup` object. The `onCleanup` object goes out of scope at the point you expect it to, and everything's fine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's slightly more complicated. The anonymous function does grab a snapshot of the entire workspace, including the timer object handle, but this in itself shouldn't be a problem, as MATLAB should spot the cyclic dependency. The reason it can't is explained here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/39858-clearing-handle-subclasses-with-timer-objects and is to do with timer objects being java objects.

Comment: @user664303 Good point. Perhaps I'm wrong though, but I think that's a separate issue that's not relevant here. In this case, MATLAB doesn't even get to the point of failing to find the cyclic dependency between the timer and the `onCleanup` object, because there's still a reference to the timer in the base workspace.

Comment: I see. Indeed, the documentation states that timer objects should always be deleted manually, suggesting that they're not deleted automatically: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html

Comment: thanks for the detailed enlightening answer, I am new to Matlab and such annoyances can drive one crazy since its completely counter-intuitive!

Comment: I would hesitate to say timers are created or referenced in the base workspace though, because `whos` doesn't list them there and `clear` and `clear all` don't destroy them. They are a law unto themselves!

Comment: @user664303 I'm sorry - you're correct that it was misleading of me to describe them as being in the base workspace. If you look into the `timer` function, you'll see that it calls the function `mltimerpackage`. Timer objects are stored in an mlocked persistent variable within `mltimerpackage`, that acts as a sort of register for timer objects. The functions `timerfind` and `timerfindall` also call `mltimerpackage` in order to retrieve timer objects. In any case, there's a reference to them stored outside the local function scope, which is the relevant thing for the question.

Answer (score 1):

a possible workaround (found by a colleague of me) is to move to definition of the timer into a own function. It is not clear to us why this works but it seems that the definition of a timer in matlab changes the context of some local variables of the function which are not 'deleted' after the function ends as it would be expected from the matlab documentation ([Object Life cycle of variables in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html#btavjj2-1))

A working example is shown below (it uses the defined timer to print simple status messages while waiting) and upon Ctrl+c or when the function ends the Timer is stopped. It furthermore makes sure that only one timer with the name 'timer-mywait' is defined.

```
function mytest3(time)
% register Cleanup handler
c = onCleanup(@()onCleanup_fcn);

t = mywait_timer(time);
wait(t);

% onCleanup handle function
function onCleanup_fcn
    tm = timerfind('Name','timer-mywait');
    if ~isempty(tm) && any(strcmpi(get(tm,'running'),'on'))
    disp('Stopped running timer ''timer-mywait''!');
    stop(tm); 
    end
end % onCleanup_fcn
end %mytest3

function t = mywait_timer(time)
    N = 5;    
    t = timerfind('Name','timer-mywait');
    if isempty(t) % avoid multiple definitions of the same timer
    t = timer();
    end
    t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
    t.TasksToExecute = N+1;
    t.Period = str2num(sprintf('%.3f',time/N)); % Matlab complains about more digits!
    t.Name = 'timer-mywait';
    t.TimerFcn = @(o,s)mywait_timercb();
    start(t),
end % mywait_timer

function mywait_timercb()
disp(' still waiting ... ');
end % mywait_timercb
```